# How to maintain null for numeric values when using BeanUtils.copyProperties?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, struts

I have a numeric database field (numeric(3) in SQL Server 2000) that allows nulls, and null is my preferred "no value" value.

That field is mapped to the non-primitive java `Long` class in Hibernate:

`<property column="my_column" name="my_column" type="java.lang.Long" not-null="false" />`

The field is set as `java.lang.Long` in both my struts form and bean.  When the Struts form is first created, I've verified that the property returns null.  When the bean is created (pulled from the database), I've verified that the property returns null. However, after using `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` to prefill the Struts form with the bean values, the property then returns 0, and if I continue and save the form the database will have the 0 value.

Am I using the wrong types or combination of types (in database and/or Hibernate/Java) to maintain a null value for a numeric field?  Should I map the numeric sql type to a different Java class like `BigDecimal`? In researching, I've found mention of a `Converter` class. Do I need to create such a class to help `BeanUtils` properly maintain null values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register a LongConverter with null for a default value in BeanUtils.

```
ConvertUtils.register(new LongConverter(null), Long.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. I added `ConvertUtils.register(new LongConverter(null), Long.class);` just before the copy properties call and that fixed it. However, is that the best place to register the Long converter? From what I've read, converter registration is global, so should this be registered elsewhere and, if so, where?

Comment: I moved the registration call to an initialization servlet for the application so it now works globally. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like the right place to do it, sorry for not replying.

Comment: Please edit the answer. It's ConvertUtils but BeanUtils. ConvertUtils.register(new LongConverter(null), Long.class);

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml use below code

```
<init-param>
      <param-name>convertNull</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

So this converts the default 0 to null.